# NameError: name 'conn' is not defined

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, mqtt

In pycharm I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL database and MQTT. In the last part of my code I have a "#Get Cursor" segment.

When running the code, I am getting: "NameError: name 'conn' is not defined.

The error happens with `cur = conn.cursor()`

In other projects I have not defined the conn, but it still worked. I have some trouble finding the reason for the to happen..

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75864530/edit) the question to show a lot more of the code, without seeing where `conn` is defined it's impossible to say why it's not found when you just show the line of code where it's not found... (`conn` is not defined in other projects then it must not be used)

Comment: You should define `conn` every time.  Also on other poroject you defined it, else where do you connect to get the data? (host, port, database, protocol, etc. need to be defined). And BTW: there is nothing about PyCharm in your question.